# Display error message depending on if user is disabled or if input is invalid using JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display an error message under the 'Email Address' input if the user is disabled and display a separate error message if the user is invalid under the 'Password' input.  When debugging I found that if a user is disabled the "Status code is 503" and if the input is invalid the "Status code is 400".

HTML

```
<md-content id="login" layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="inputdemoErrors">
<div flex="25"></div>
  <p class="m0">project</p>
    <form id="loginForm">
      <md-input-container>
        <label for="username">Email Address</label>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="email-field">
        <input name="username" id="username" type="email" class="validate" ng-model="username" enter-key="submitLogin()" autocomplete="off" required>
        <div ng-show="disabled" ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" role="alert">
          <div ng-message="required">User Account is Disabled</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="password-field">
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="validate" ng-model="password" enter-key="submitLogin()" autocomplete="off" required>
        <div ng-show="invalid" ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" role="alert">
          <div ng-message="required">Invalid Email or Password</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" style="width: 100%; margin: 0; background-color: #29B6F6;" ng-click="submitLogin()">Login</a>
  </form>
</md-content>
```

JS

```
  angular
   .module('login')
   .controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

  function LoginCtrl($scope, $location, SecService, RecService, Service) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ctrlName = 'LoginCtrl';

  $scope.submitLogin = function() {
  $scope.invalid = $scope.loginForm.$invalid;
  if($scope.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  else
    $scope.dataLoading = true;
    var creds = {
      username: $scope.username,
      password: $scope.password
    };
    SecService.login(creds).then(function (response) {
      if (response.success) {
        RecService.connect();
        SecService.setCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
        Service.loadCurrentUser();
        $location.path('/main');
      } 
      if (response = 503)
      {
        $scope.disabled = $scope.loginForm.$disabled;
        if ($scope.invalid) return invalid;
      }
      if (response = 400)
      {
        $scope.invalid = $scope.loginForm.$invalid;
        if ($scope.invalid) return invalid;
      }
    });
  };
 }
}());
```

I am trying to display "User Account is Disabled" if the user is disabled (503), and "Email or Password is Invalid" if they have an invalid input (400).  This should happen when the login button is clicked.

Comment: Nice one Devon. You don't have a problem that I can see in your huge code dump. Please make an edit and specify a problem that you are having. If you can write clean angular code, surely you can check the http return code and conditionally display DOM elements...

Comment: If I didn't have a problem I wouldn't have posted on stackoverflow.  I did remove some code, but I want to make sure you have all the info you need to provide help.  I didn't write all of this angular code myself and I am actually new to the stuff.  So if you don't mind please only respond with helpful comments or don't respond at all.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to give a good answer without knowing what functionality you want with the `ng-messages`.

If you omit `ng-messages`:

```
<div ng-show="showDisabled">
  User Account is Disabled
</div>
<div ng-show="showInvalid">
  Invalid Email or Password
</div>
```

The following doesn't look right, so remove it for now:

```
if (response = 503)
{
  $scope.disabled = $scope.loginForm.$disabled;
  if ($scope.invalid) return invalid;
}
if (response = 400)
{
  $scope.invalid = $scope.loginForm.$invalid;
  if ($scope.invalid) return invalid;
}
```

It doesn't look like the return values are used anywhere and it should be `response === x`, not `response = x`.

Replace with:

```
$scope.showDisabled = response === 503;
$scope.showInvalid = response === 400;
```

Another note, if you need to access the form like this:

```
ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error"
```

The form needs a `name`:

```
<form name="loginForm">
```

Instead of `id`:

```
<form id="loginForm">
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.  That made it simple compared to what I was doing.